# Regex for all files except .hg_keep

Tags: regex, mercurial, hgignore

I use empty `.hg_keep` files to keep some (otherwise empty) folders in Mercurial.

The problem is that I can't find a working regex which excludes everything but the `.hg_keep` files.

lets say we have this filestructure:

```
a/b/c2/.hg_keep
a/b/c/d/.hg_keep
a/b/c/d/file1
a/b/c/d2/.hg_keep
a/b/.hg_keep
a/b/file2
a/b/file1
a/.hg_keep
a/file2
a/file1
```

and I want to keep only the `.hg_keep` files under `a/b/`.

with the help of http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ I created the following `.hgignore`:

```
syntax: regexp
.*b.*/(?!.*\.hg_keep)
```

but Mercurial ignores all `.hg_keep` files in subfolders of `b`.

```
# hg status
? .hgignore
? a/.hg_keep
? a/b/.hg_keep
? a/file1
? a/file

# hg status -i
I a/b/c/d/.hg_keep
I a/b/c/d/file1
I a/b/c/d2/.hg_keep
I a/b/c2/.hg_keep
I a/b/file1
I a/b/file2
```

I know that I a can `hd add` all the `.hg_keep` files, but is there a solution with a regular expression (or glob)?

Answer (score 3):

Regexp negation might work for this. If you want to ignore everything *except* the `a/b/.hg_keep` file, you can probably use:

```
^(?!a/b/\.hg_keep)$
```

The parts of this regexp that matter are:

```
^                   anchor the match to the beginning of the file path
(?!  ... )          negation of the expression between '!' and ')'
a/b/\.hg_keep       the full path of the file you want to match
$                   anchor the match to the end of the file path
```

The regular expression

```
^a/b/\.hg_keep$
```

would match *only* the file called `a/b/.hg_keep`.

Its negation

```
^(?!a/b/\.hg_keep)$
```

will match everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure in what context you are using the Regex but this should be it, this matches all lines ending in `.hg_keep`:

```
^.*\.hg_keep$
```

**EDIT:** And here is a Regex to match items not matching the above expression:

```
^(?:(?!.*\.hg_keep).)*$
```

Comment: Those are the only lines he needs to not match--this is for the .hgignore file.

Comment: Works in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but not in .hgignore. Maybe a problem with the regex-parsing in mercurial?
Also it matches the files "a/file1" and "a/file2" which i want to keep.

Comment: @rmweiss Sorry not familiar with mercurial's quirks

Answer (score 0):

Try `(?!.*/\.hg_keep$)`.

Comment: Doesn't work. With this in .hgignore it ignores all files.
Please remember that i want to keep "a/file1" and "a/file2".

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something similiar to this.
Found an answer, but it's not what we want to hear.

> 3. Limitations
>
> There is no straightforward way to ignore all but a set of files. Attempting to use an inverted regex match will fail when combined with other patterns. This is an intentional limitation, as alternate formats were all considered far too likely to confuse users to be worth the additional flexibility.
>
> Ref: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/.hgignore